# Unwanted new tab opens every time I click on a link which is not expected

Tags: java, ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have an issue with my automation (selenium-webdriver). Every time I click on a link, that link would open in a new tab (this is not expected, and links do not have _blank attr. set to them), my automation fails cause it stays on the first tab.

I've tried setting up a new automation env on a new PC - same result. I've tried releasing Ctrl key using :controlKeyUp - same result

This issue happened during bug-fixes merge from v1 to v2 of my product.

P.S.:

- On a version with older code automation works fine with no issues
- This issue is not reproducible manually.

Comment: (1) Java or Ruby ? (2) Can you post the line where you click on the element ? (I want to be sure that there is a click, not a Ctrl + T) (3) Which is the version of your Selenium ?

Comment: 1. I've tried this on java and on ruby test environment so both/any

Comment: 2.  browser.find_element(:id, "aSignIn").click

Comment: 3. Selenium-webdriver 2.44

Comment: what browser is used for the emulation ? Chrome ? Firefox ?

Comment: I've tried it in IE,Chrome, FF. Older and new versions.

Comment: If the problem only happened after code changes to your product, it would help to know what those changes were.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will explain how we dealt with the issue.

We've implemented Google Analytics event tracking on our site, so it would check every link to see if it is an external one. A reg-ex for that was written to check links, but it did not incorporate the way I was bypassing basic authentication "http://LOGIN:PASSWORD@yoursite.com". Therefore GA thought every link was an external one and GA injected its .js with "_blank" attribute.